# Demonstration of Forward Time Central Space in Python's matplotlib animation package

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I want to create a simple animation of how bad the Forward Time Central Space (FTCS) solves the flux conservation equation for a Gaussian velocity distribution (*"Physics... yeah!"*). I have written a small animation based on [this tutorial](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/). I have attached the code below. I'm satisfied with it (given that I don't really know anything about matplotlib's animation package), but I cannot get the animation to be slow enough so that I can actually see something.

This boils down to me not understanding how to set the parameters in the **animation.FuncAnimation** in the last line of the code. Could anybody explain, help?

```
import math
import numpy as np
import scipy as sci
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

#generate velocity distribution
sigma = 1.
xZero = 0.
N = 101
x = np.linspace(-10,10,N)
uZero = 1. / math.sqrt(2 * math.pi * (sigma**2)) * np.exp(-0.5*((x - xZero)/(2*sigma))**2)


v = 1
xStep = x[2]-x[1]
tStep = 0.1
alpha = v * tStep/xStep * 0.5

#include boundary conditions
u = np.hstack((0.,uZero,0.))
uNext = np.zeros(N + 2)

#solve with forward time central space and store each outer loop in data
#so it can be used in the animation
data = []
data.append(u[1:-1])
for n in range(0,100):
    for i in range(1,N+1):
        uNext[i] = -alpha * u[i+1] + u[i] + alpha*u[i-1] 
    u = uNext
    data.append(u[1:-1])
data = np.array(data)

#launch up the animation
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-10,10),ylim=(-1,1))
line, = ax.plot([],[],lw=2)

def init():
    line.set_data([],[])
    return line,

#get the data for animation from the data array
def animate(i):
    y = data[i]
    line.set_data(x,y)
    return line,

#the actual animation
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,init_func=init,frames=200,interval=2000,blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explore your data variable first. If i run your code, only data[0] and data[1] are different, from data[1] onwards all data (thus frames) are the same.

```
np.allclose(data[1], data[100])
True
```

Comment: thank you! I put *uNext = np.zeros(N + 2)* inside the outer for loop and that fixes it.